# Create an input(s) that depends on a multiple select which will add/subtract the values of the input(s)

Tags: javascript, select, input

I am creating an automatic counter in JS, where from selecting multiple options in a select, each of these options, which are Features, send a numerical figure determined by a numerical cost, thus sending the figure to the same input (or several).

My intention is that by placing these figures, you will be in the input in general, or on the contrary, three inputs, in this way: X/Y/Z.

So, the X value will correspond with the positive numerical values, the Y value with the negative numerical values, and finally, the Z value with the difference of both, being able to remain a positive number or 0 only, in the case of appearing a negative number that appears some type of error that does not let continue.

For example, the positive feature "Big Body" will generate -5, while the positive feature "With Reflections" will generate -6. In this case, I would like the negative value to appear without the dash that indicates it is a negative number. The values would be added together when I add them, that is, if I add the positive "Large Body" and "Reflected" Traits it would generate a total of -11.

On the other hand, there would be an initial number in the positive input, i.e. in X of 10.

In principle, the select will cover about 50 values, dividing the traits into positive and negative. Positive variables will always generate a negative number, while negative variables will generate a positive number.

I really don't know how I could develop this, since the idea is to incorporate it into a form-generator that I have made. I leave you for now what I have done, so you can see the basic idea.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> 
</script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"> 
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css">

<select name="rasgos" class="multipleChosen rasgos" multiple="true">
  <optgroup label="Positivos"><option value="Cuerpo grande">Cuerpo grande</option>
  <option value="Musculoso">Musculoso</option>
  <option value="Ágil">Ágil</option>
  <option value="Con reflejos">Con reflejos</option>
  <option value="Preciso">Preciso</option>
  <option value="Afortunado">Afortunado</option>
  <option value="Atento">Atento</option>
  <option value="Agraciado">Agraciado</option>
  <option value="Vivaz">Vivaz</option>
  <option value="Culto">Culto</option>
  <option value="Noble">Noble</option>
  <option value="Líder">Líder</option>
  <option value="Defensor">Defensor</option>
  <option value="Precavido">Precavido</option>
  <option value="Orador">Orador</option>
  <option value="Sagaz">Sagaz</option>
  <option value="Aprendizaje rápido">Aprendizaje rápido</option>
  <option value="Crematomano">Crematomano</option>
  <option value="Regateador">Regateador</option>
  <option value="Domador">Domador</option>
  <optgroup label="Negativos">
  <option value="En los huesos">En los huesos</option>
  <option value="Débil">Débil</option>
  <option value="Lento">Lento</option>
  <option value="Vago">Vago</option>
  <option value="Glotón">Glotón</option>
  <option value="Sin reflejos">Sin reflejos</option>
  <option value="Sin puntería">Sin puntería</option>
  <option value="Torpe">Torpe</option>
  <option value="Dócil">Dócil</option>
  <option value="Honesto">Honesto</option>
  <option value="Obstuto">Obstuto</option>
  <option value="Mal oído">Mal oído</option>
  <option value="Feo">Feo</option>
  <option value="Estéril">Estéril</option>
  <option value="Aprendizaje lento">Aprendizaje lento</option>
  <option value="Testarudo">Testarudo</option>
  <option value="Tartamudo">Tartamudo</option>
  <option value="Disoluto">Disoluto</option>
  <option value="Ceguera">Ceguera</option>
  <option value="Enfermizo">Enfermizo</option>
</select>
<input type="text" disabled="" name="puntosrasgos" class="alin" value="" placeholder="Puntos de Rasgo [PR]"/>

<script>
$('.rasgos').on('change', function() {
var value =this.value;
    if(value == 'Cuerpo grande')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-5');
    }
    
  if(value == 'Musculoso')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-5');
    }
  
   if(value == 'Ágil')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-5');
    }
  
   if(value == 'Con reflejos')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-6');
    }
  
  if(value == 'Preciso')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-6');
    }
  if(value == 'Afortunado')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-6');
    }
    
  if(value == 'Atento')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-4');
    }
  
   if(value == 'Agraciado')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-5');
    }
  
   if(value == 'Vivaz')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-4');
    }
  
  if(value == 'Culto')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-4');
    }
  if(value == 'Noble')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-4');
    }
    
  if(value == 'Líder')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-6');
    }
  
   if(value == 'Defensor')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-6');
    }
  
   if(value == 'Precavido')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-6');
    }
  
  if(value == 'Orador')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-5');
    }
  if(value == 'Sagaz')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-5');
    }
    
  if(value == 'Aprendizaje  rápido')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-6');
    }
  
   if(value == 'Crematomano')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-4');
    }
  
   if(value == 'Regateador')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-4');
    }
  
  if(value == 'Domador')
    {
        $('.alin').val('-5');
    }
    if(value == 'En los huesos')
    {
        $('.alin').val('4');
    }
    
  if(value == 'Débil')
    {
        $('.alin').val('5');
    }
  
   if(value == 'Lento')
    {
        $('.alin').val('5');
    }
  
   if(value == 'Vago')
    {
        $('.alin').val('3');
    }
  
  if(value == 'Glotón')
    {
        $('.alin').val('3');
    }
});
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
  //Chosen
  $(".multipleChosen").chosen({
      placeholder_text_multiple: "Rasgos" //placeholder
 });
  //Select2
  $(".multipleSelect2").select2({
  placeholder: "Rasgos" //placeholder
 });
})

$('.multipleChosen.rasgos')
  
  
</script>
```

Could someone provide me with the basic JS code to add it on my own? Thank you very much, I'm waiting for your answer!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. You have a select where you can choose multiple options. You want to create 3 inputs: one with the sum of all the positive features (X), one with the sum of all the negative features (Y) and a third one (Z) which is the sum of Y and X?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. Whether the result of the summation goes to a general input with three sections: X/Y/Z, or, three different ones, one for X, one for Y, and the last one for Z.

Comment: There is no benefit to adding the `value` declaration in an option tag if the text is identical.  In other words, you can safely omit all of the redundant `value="sameAsText"` declarations because they are unnecessarily bloating your markup.

Answer (score 0):

I created a JSFiddle with a possible solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/7b8294ej/

- I removed the `select2` library because it seems to be doing a very similar job to the `chosen` library.
- I used the custom attribute "data-cost" instead of manually initializing the cost using jQuery.
- I closed the `optgroup` tags.

General strategy:

You need to listen to the change event the select is sending every time an option is selected/deselected. Every time a change happens, we re-calculate the costs and update the inputs.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for!

But there would be some way to add, for example, the final number of the Total, be it 0 or values greater than 0.

And on the other hand, to establish a maximum value of numbers, both positive and negative? for example, maximum 20 and -20.

(And the last thing - add something like incompatibilities, where for example "Cuerpo grande" and "En los huesos" are incompatible, and you can't mark them together).

I know I can ask a lot, but I would be very grateful if you help me, I am really new to the subject :(